# 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not subscriptable django

Tags: python, django

Есть 2 объекта с отношением многие ко многим, пытаюсь получить доступ в шаблоне к одному через другой и выскакивает ошибка:

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not subscriptable
```

html:

```
{% for room in all_rooms %}
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:style' rmslg=room.slug stslg=room.styles|first %}">{{ room.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
```

Решение:

```
{% with room.styles.all|first as style_default %} 
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:style' rmslg=room.slug stslg=style_default.slug %}">{{ room.name }}</a></li>
                {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каком то из полей room у тебя связь ManyToManyField, которая вызывает ошибку, мне кажется ошибка в строке:

`stslg=room.styles|first`

Попробуй изменить ее так: 
`stslg=room.styles.all|first`

Можешь посмотреть эти ответы об обработке ManyToManyField в Django Templates:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411961/querying-many-to-many-fields-in-django-template/3411979

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270330/django-show-a-manytomanyfield-in-a-template

Comment: да верно ту ошибку я уже исправил, нужно было обращаться к полю slug(stslg=room.styles.slug|first). Но возникла другая этой строкой он ничего не находит, хотя слаг есть, а ту строку, которую порекомендовали вы он отрабатывает и выводит название. Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: Исправил при помощи добавления with(добавил в вопрос так нагляднее)